# Connect to remote PostgreSQL cluster via TLS/SSL from behind HTTP proxy

Tags: postgresql, http, ssh, proxy, http-proxy

I've got a [Flexible PostgreSQL Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/overview) hosted on [MS Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/). This server requires TLS/SSL access like shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-tls-ssl), e.g.:

```bash
psql "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=c:\ssl\DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem host=mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com dbname=postgres user=myadmin"
```

or without "verify-full" it works as well:

```bash
psql "sslmode=require host=mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com dbname=postgres user=myadmin"
```

Everything works fine when I connect directly, not using a proxy server. But at office we have a corporate HTTP proxy / Firewall configured like `http://192.168.X.X:3128`. When the proxy is activated, connection to Azure fails.

I was trying to use `ssh` to set up a proxy tunnel, like so:

```bash
ssh -p 5432 <Azure DB username>@<Azure DB host: ....database.azure.com> -L 3128:192.168.X.X:5432
```

But that didn't work (connection time out error). Also tried to configure connection via PuTTY using [some examples](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/38-PuTTY-for-SSH-Tunneling-to-PostgreSQL-Server.html) from the web, but also to no avail.

Question is: is it at all possible to connect to a remote cluster (both Azure and Google Cloud enforce SSH access) from behind an HTTP proxy?

Comment: If the proxy supports [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Comparison_to_HTTP_proxying) that may be an option. SSH tunnelling requires an SSH server (e.g. [sshd](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/)) with tunnelling enabled (and this assumes your corporate firewall permits outgoing ssh connections!); probably simpler and safer to request a change to the corporate firewall rules.

Comment: I don't understand what an HTTP proxy has to do with this.  PostgreSQL does not speak HTTP, nor does it run on a port number classically used for HTTP.

Comment: "When the proxy is activated, connection to Azure fails."  With what error?

Comment: "both Azure and Google Cloud enforce SSH access"  What does this mean?  Did you confuse SSL with SSH?

Comment: `ssh -p 5432...` this could only work if the machine you are connecting to is running sshd on the port usually used by PostgreSQL.  That is exceedingly unlikely.  You might want ssh to tunnel from/to some other port, but you still needs to use ssh's actual port to establish the tunnel.  Does your ssh command work if you leave off the `-L`?  If not, then it isn't going to work with it, either.

Comment: Azure requires TLS/SSL 1.2 or higher. To do that, the psql connection string must have "sslmode=require" or "sslmode=verify-full" (and then the root certificate must be attached). So I cannot use any of these options behind the HTTP proxy.